# Using ctypes to pass 2D array of ints from python to C++

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to pass a double array of ints from python to a C++ library using ctypes.  Unfortunately, I get a segfault when I attempt to read the array entries on the C++ side.  What is the right way to do this?

Here is my python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from ctypes import *

# load the extension lib
testLib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libtest.so')
# build adjacency matrix
numNodes = 5
MatrixRowType = c_int * numNodes
MatrixType = MatrixRowType * numNodes
adj = MatrixType()
for i in range(0, numNodes):
    for j in range(0, numNodes):
        adj[i][j] = c_int(0)
adj[0][0] = c_int(42)
for i in range(numNodes):
    print ' matrix value ', adj[i][0]
testLib.test_bridge(numNodes, adj)
```

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    int test_bridge(int numNodes, int** adjacencyMatrix) {
       std::cout << " numNodes:" << numNodes << '\n';
       std::cout << " passed adjacency pointer " << adjacencyMatrix << '\n';
       std::cout << adjacencyMatrix[0][0] << std::endl;   // should be "42", instead we crash
    }
}
```

Comment: The C++ code doesn't use a contiguous 2D array. It uses a 1D array of `int` pointers to the rows, i.e. `adjacencyMatrix[0]` points to an `int` array of `numNodes` elements. You need to either create such an array in ctypes or modify your C++ code to work with a contiguous 2D array.  The latter is a bit cumbersome since the array is passed as a pointer to the first element and the machine code isn't compiled to handle a dynamic array. So you end up doing array arithmetic,  e.g. `adjacencyMatrix[i * numNodes + j]`.

Comment: In case it's not obvious how to create the array of pointers from your existing 2D array: `p_adj = (POINTER(c_int) * numNodes)(*adj)`.